# An inequality needed for contraction in Volterra Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I have stuck on something which I guess should be kind of trivial.

Let $D=[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$, $a\geq 0$, $\lambda>0$ and $\varphi:C(D,\mathbb R)\to C(D,\mathbb R)$

$$\varphi(f)(x)=\lambda\int_a^x K(x,y)f(y)dy+\alpha(x)$$ for every $x\in D$.

For $g,h\in C(D,\mathbb R)$, let $M=\sup_{x,y}|K(x,y)|$ and $t=\sup_x|g(x)-h(x)|$.

I want to show that $$sup_{x\in D}|\varphi^n(g)-\varphi^n(h)|\leq \frac{t\left(\lambda M(b-a)\right)^n}{n!}$$

Clearly I see that $$sup_{x\in D}|\varphi(g)-\varphi(h)|\leq \lambda Mt(b-a)$$ and the best I can do yet is to receive 
$$sup_{x\in D}|\varphi^n(g)-\varphi^n(h)|\leq t^{n-1}\left(\lambda M(b-a)\right)^n$$ by induction.

But how to receive the inequality I need, first of all where $n!$ comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for some $n$ and all $z\in [a,b]$ that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,z]}|\varphi^n(g)(x)-\varphi^n(h)(x)|\leq 
\left(\sup_{x\in [0,z]}|g(x)-h(x)|\right)\frac{(z-a)^n\left(\lambda M\right)^n}{n!},$$
(note it is satisfied by $n=1$).
Then for $n+1$,
we have for all $z\in [a,b]$ that
\begin{align*}
&\sup_{x\in [0,z]}|\varphi^{n+1}(f)(x)-\varphi^{n+1}(g)(x)|\\
&\le \sup_{x\in [0,z]} \lambda\int_a^x |K(x,y)||\varphi^n(g)(y)-\varphi^n(h)(y)|dy\\
&\le \sup_{x\in [0,z]}\lambda M\int_a^x 
\left(\sup_{s\in [0,y]}|g(s)-h(s)|\right)\frac{(y-a)^n\left(\lambda M\right)^n}{n!} dy\\
&\le \left(\sup_{x\in [0,z]}|g(x)-h(x)|\right)\lambda M\int_a^z \frac{(y-a)^n\left(\lambda M\right)^n}{n!} dy\\
&= \left(\sup_{x\in [0,z]}|g(x)-h(x)|\right) \frac{(\lambda M)^{n+1}}{n!}\frac{ (z-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}.
\end{align*}